# Disable Babel Modules When Using Multiple Presets

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I just upgraded to webpack 2 and it recommends turning off modules for Babel as it now has the ability to do it itself. I am using both react and es2015 and therefore tried the .babelrc config below, but it does not compile. Logger.js throws an exception Babel 5 option: base.modules - use the corresponding module transform plugin...

```
"presets": ["react", "es2015", { modules: false }]
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up adding the config into module rules in webpack.

```
{
      test: /\.js$|\.jsx$/, 
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: [
              ['react'],                    
              ['es2015', { modules: false }]
            ]
        }
      }
  }
```